# Trouble getting guest machine on virt-manager to connect to other computers on the same network outside of the host device

Tags: linux, debian, networking, virt-manager

I am using `virt-manager` and I am currently having trouble trying to get my guest OS to connect to other machines outside of my host machine.

Both the host and guest operating systems are Linux (Debian based.) I have gotten the guest and host to connect to each other with the use of `netcat`, but can't do the same with any computer that is outside the host, while it is also on the same network.

I thank you in advance for your time.

I have disabled the firewall for both the host and guest, but still I am unable to connect to any device that is on the same network.

virt-manager settings here:
[image]

ifconfig here:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question adding details of the network configuration (devices, IPs, etc) on each OS, and what exactly do you mean by "can't connect".

Comment: what I exactly mean by "can't connect" is that I can get any device (in this case, a windows laptop) to connect to my virtual machine, that is on the same network that is also outside of the computer that I am hosting the virtual machine on.

Comment: Virt-manager may be a god tool, but I recommend to read qemu doc (about networking), while there are more possibilities. Namely you chose **bridge device** but `ifconfig` displays `lo` and `eth0` only, and no `vibr0` interface. Some other things has to be configured to enable use of `qemu-bridge-helper`. The `vibr0` should be a master of `eth0`, too. I may show you my VM starting script, but it is as simple as it can be, using direct call of `qemu-system-x86_64` without virt-manager assistance.

Comment: @schweik OP showed the hypervisor's configuration in the 1st screenshot, and the VM's configuration in the 2nd screenshot, as the MAC address of eth0 shows (it matches the address in the 1st screenshot). So that's normal the VM has no bridge: it's on the hypervisor which wasn't displayed here.

Comment: Beside, I'm not sure it's a good idea to choose as bridge device a bridge managed by libvirt. Either use the libvirt's name (eg: default for virbr0) or a bridge not managed by libvirt. The managed bridge has a specific libvirt property that would have been displayed when using its libvirt name, such as NAT for the usual default bridge. In case the property is not NAT but for example "isolated network", it could be restricted. eg: https://wiki.libvirt.org/VirtualNetworking.html#isolated-mode